# Don't they include resource kit in windows XP SP3?

Tags: windows-xp, service-pack

I've Windows XP SP3 installed on my computer. [XP Resource Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=18546) (Windows XP Service Pack 2 Support Tools) which was released for SP2. So, does that mean I've these tools installed on my PC? I tried checking by executing few commands from that RC but they aren't found.

But their website says, "The following is a list of all Support Tools in Service Pack 2:". And having SP3 installed means SP2 is also installed right? So, why doesn't my computer have these tools?

Its confusing!

Comment: What tool(s) specifically are you looking for? You should still be able to download just the tools you want/need without needing to download and extract the whole SP file.

Comment: dupfinder.exe & few others..

Comment: SP2 contains those tools, but that doesn't mean it installs them automatically. Have you tried installing the support tools? Just because there isn't an "SP3 version" doesn't mean they won't work in SP3.

Comment: @shufler: No! Why would I install it? web page says, this support tool is part of SP2. And I have SP3 which includes SP2. Am I wrong?

Comment: If you extract SP2, in theory there is a Support\Tools folder with a Setup.exe that installs them (as there is on a Windows XP CD). Following this this theory SP3 may include it, but the logic SP3 contains SP2 doesn't follow that the support tools are in SP3.